# Why don't these parameters go through in this Mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong with this query?

I can't get this query to pass these arguments!

```
$offset = 5;
$rowsperpage = 10;
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT ?,?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($offset, $rowsperpage))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['title'];
  }
}
```

If I change the query to this it works fine, but I need to pass the strings because they are dynamic.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5,10");
if ($stmt->execute(array($offset, $rowsperpage))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['title'];
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that it's giving you?

Comment: No error is given. Nothing shows up!

Comment: If I replace ?,? with something like 4,10 the posts show up.

Comment: Your table is called `table`?

Comment: My table is called something else, I renamed it for the sake of a readable example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a feeling that "lazy execution" treats all parameters as strings and thus enclose them in quotes.

So, either bind your parameters explicitly, using bind_param instead of passing array into execute()

or set emulation mode to off

```
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

right after connect.

anyway, you have to get in touch with the error message first.
So, setting this one

```
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

will reveal the error message to you

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to do the [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to fill in the blanks

Comment: not necessary - the parameters are being filled in from the array passed in to the `->execute()` call.